# How can I scale a div with css transform but keep the contents unscaled?

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions, css-transforms

I am trying to create the effect of expanding a div to reveal more of an image but at the moment, the image expands with the div scaling. I currently expand the div like so;

```
.panel:hover {
  transform: scaleX(1.5);
  z-index: 10;
}
```

I have tried appling the transformation to parent attributes such as the list and anchor tags with no luck. Here is my codepen

http://codepen.io/duncanmolesworth/pen/LRdKYj

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is kind of zooming the panel, what you want to do is increase its width.

You can try this:

```
.panel:hover {
   width: 150%;
   left: -25%;
   z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Is there any way i could keep the smooth expanding transition?

Comment: You should accept the answer if it satisfies your question.
Unfortunately `transition` and `webkit-transition` won't work in this situation. That's the only simple method I know to animate just using CSS, maybe someone else knows another way.